# Primefaces DataTable column width control OR alternative Solution?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces datatable and my code something like this

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTableBonusSplit" var="announcements"
    value="#{announcementBean.dataList}" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="550"
     paginator="true" rows="10"
    paginatorPosition="bottom"
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" sortMode="multiple">


    <p:column headerText="Company"
        sortBy="#{announcementBean.cName}" style="width:110px;"
        styleClass="wrap" for="companyName">

        <h:outputText value="#{announcements.companyName}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Type" style="width:110px;"
        styleClass="wrap" sortBy="#{announcements.announcementType}">
        <h:outputText value="#{announcements.announcementType}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Date" style="width:110px;"
        styleClass="wrap" sortBy="#{announcements.announcementDt}">
        <h:outputText value="#{announcements.announcementDt}">
        <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd/MMM/yyyy" />
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Announcement" style="table-layout: fixed;white-space: normal;"
        sortBy="#{announcements.announcement}"  >
        <h:outputText value="#{announcements.announcement}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

and you can see the image [image]if you will the table its look very bad any good solution for this.

Comment: What you mean by `looks very bad`? You refer to the `Announcement` column? Please edit your question as what you ask is too broad and unclear to be covered.

Comment: My Question is simple i want to show Announcement but its contain lots of data so its look and feel is very worst

Comment: So why don't you just reduce the shown character number using java?

Answer (score -1):

Just use `fn:substring()` combined with `fn:length()`:

```
<h:outputText value="#{fn:length(announcements.announcement) > 50 ? fn:substring(announcements.announcement,0,50) : announcements.announcement}"  />
```

That will render the shortened output if the character count is greater than 50.

Comment: I got javax.el.ELException: Function 'fn:length' not found

Comment: Done first exception ...But it will show 50 Character what about other data how we will show that?

Comment: That's something you should decide by yourself! [Here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tooltip.jsf) you have a tip